# make a dataframe from many json files

Tags: python, json, pandas

I try to read multiple json files, make a dataframe with each of the files and then concatenate all those dataframes in one dataframe but the program makes only one dataframe with the last file it reads without errors. All the json files have the same structure. Do you know what to change in my code?

The code is the following:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os

df1=None
path = 'C:\\Users\\sotir\\Desktop\\machinedataset'
filenames = os.listdir(path)

for filename in sorted(filenames):
    if filename.startswith("mpd.slice") and filename.endswith(".json"):
        fullpath = os.sep.join((path, filename))
        f = open(fullpath)
        js = json.load(f)
        f.close()
        df= pd.json_normalize(js['playlists'], meta=['name', 'collaborative', 'pid', 'modified_at','num_tracks', 'num_albums',
                                              'num_followers', 'num_edits', 'duration_ms', 'num_artists'],record_path= ['tracks'],
                       record_prefix='_')
        if df1==None:
            df1= df
        else:
            
            df1=pd.concat([df1,df])
```

I updated the code but I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20464/3545215146.py in <module>
     16                                               'num_followers', 'num_edits', 'duration_ms', 'num_artists'],record_path= ['tracks'],
     17                        record_prefix='_')
---> 18         if df1==None:
     19             df1= df
     20         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1440     @final
   1441     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1442         raise ValueError(
   1443             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1444             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: You probably want to do something like `df1=None; ...; df=pd. ...; if df1=None: df1=df; else: df1=pd.concat([df1,df])`

Comment: I updated the code but I get an error

Answer (score 0):

`df1==None` returns a `DataFrame` full of values - potentially both `True` and `False`. When you pass such an object to `if` it does not know how to deal with it so it just throws an error. To fix this error, replace with:

```py
if df1 is None:
```

In any case, why don't you get all of these dataframes into a list first and then call `pd.concat` just once?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I changed the aforementioned line to                  if df1 is None: but I get only the data from one file instead of all the files. Could you tell me how to get all these dataframes into a list and then call pd.concat? (Sorry I am new to programming)

Comment: Maybe it’s because only the first file satisfies your condition? Create a list before the loop and append all dataframes to it (`dfs.append(df)`) and then just run `pd.concat(dfs)`